# Analyze table compute statistics - no statistics shown

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I computed statistics using:

*analyze table lineitem_monthly compute statistics* for columns l_orderkey;

However, when i describe the table i dont see any statistics. What am i doing wrong? This is spark-sql build i built directly from the github code.

Tried setting the flags in conf:

```
spark.sql.statistics.histogram.enabled   true
spark.sql.cbo.enabled                    true


spark-sql> describe lineitem;
L_ORDERKEY  bigint  NULL
L_PARTKEY   bigint  NULL
L_SUPPKEY   bigint  NULL
L_LINENUMBER    int NULL
L_QUANTITY  double  NULL
L_EXTENDEDPRICE double  NULL
L_DISCOUNT  double  NULL
L_TAX   double  NULL
L_RETURNFLAG    string  NULL
L_LINESTATUS    string  NULL
L_SHIPDATE  string  NULL
L_COMMITDATE    string  NULL
L_RECEIPTDATE   string  NULL
L_SHIPINSTRUCT  string  NULL
L_SHIPMODE  string  NULL
L_COMMENT   string  NULL
Time taken: 0.039 seconds, Fetched 16 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> spark.sql("describe EXTENDED table column").show(false)

Comment: Odd. This is the way.

Comment: I have built spark myself from the master branch. Could be missing some settings? all sqls and queries work fine though.